# Recursion in C++ leads to exit code

Tags: c++, c++14, computer-science

I'm coding a Magic Wand Tool that selects every pixel similar to a starting pixel. In the script where I mark all similar pixels I have an image, a tolerance T and the starting coordinates x and y. I used recursion to code my function. The code works with a small tolerance T but if I use a bigger tolerance I get a "The process exited with code -11" error. I think the problem is too much recursion going on. The program starts at the MWT function. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
#include "mwt.h"
using namespace std;

void checkSurroundings(const Image& image, vector<vector<bool>>& seen_pixels, const int& T, 
const unsigned int& x, const unsigned int& y, int x0, int y0)
{
  seen_pixels.at(x0).at(y0) = true;
  
  if(x0 + 1 < 512 && seen_pixels.at(x0 + 1).at(y0) == false && abs(image.at(x).at(y) - image.at(x0 + 1).at(y0)) <= T)
    checkSurroundings(image, seen_pixels, T, x, y, x0 + 1, y0); 
      
  if(x0 - 1 >= 0 && seen_pixels.at(x0 - 1).at(y0) == false && abs(image.at(x).at(y) - image.at(x0 - 1).at(y0)) <= T)
    checkSurroundings(image, seen_pixels, T, x, y, x0 - 1, y0); 
    
  if(y0 + 1 < 512 && seen_pixels.at(x0).at(y0 + 1) == false && abs(image.at(x).at(y) - image.at(x0).at(y0 + 1)) <= T)
    checkSurroundings(image, seen_pixels, T, x, y, x0, y0 + 1); 
    
  if(y0 - 1 >= 0 && seen_pixels.at(x0).at(y0 - 1) == false && abs(image.at(x).at(y) - image.at(x0).at(y0 - 1)) <= T)
    checkSurroundings(image, seen_pixels, T, x, y, x0, y0 - 1);
  
  return; 
}

vector<vector<bool>> MWT(const Image& image,
                                   const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y,
                                   const unsigned int T)
{
  const unsigned int height = image.at(0).size();
  const unsigned int width = image.size();
  vector<vector<bool>> seen_pixels(width, vector<bool>(height, false));
  checkSurroundings(image, seen_pixels, T, x, y, x, y);
  return seen_pixels;
}
```

Comment: How many pixels are there? How deep can the recursion go? I think you should look for a solution without recursion.

Comment: You probably have infinite recursion, you are setting `seen_pixels` here `seen_pixels.at(x0).at(y0) = true;` but not acting on it. As the first line in `checkSurroundings` function add `if (seen_pixels.at(x0).at(y0)) {return;}` to break out of the function if you have already seen that pixel before.

Comment: Are you sure you reach a valid end condition? You could well be running into a stackoverflow otherwise. I think it is time for you to start debugging

Comment: you have no break condition.

Comment: @user20716902: If you look at the conditions of the `if` statements, they all check the `seen_pixels` array, so if `seen_pixels` holds `true` for all the neighbor pixels, it will just flow through and return. Not the cleanest way to do things by any means, but it can work nonetheless. I'm reasonably certain the problem here is with excessively deep recursion, not infinite recursion.

Comment: Even if you don't have infinite recursion. *Do not* process user-supplied data recursively. Especially not if your branching-degree is four.

Comment: Re: `if(x0 + 1 < 512 && seen_pixels.at(x0 + 1) ...` if `x0 _ 1 < 512` is a bounds check, which it seems to be, there's no need for a redundant check with `at(x0 + 1)`. seen_pixels[x0 + 1]` will work just fine, because you **know** that `x0 + 1` is a valid index. Don't waste time re-validating things that you already know are valid.

Comment: Minor style point: `const unsigned int& x` should just be `const unsigned int x`; there's no need for indirection here. And the name of that type is usually written `unsigned`; that's the same as `unsigned int`.

Comment: You probably want to use an explicit stack (or a queue) instead of recursion. Alternatively, consider using a scan-line based algorithm (though they generally require more care to get similar speed).

Comment: as others stated, you have no recursion end, additionally (if you stay with recursion) you should check "tail recursion optimization", e.g. see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tail-recursion/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through all pixels of an Image recursively is not advisable. If the Image is too large, this will overflow your stack. You should use a dynamic stack:

```
template <std::predicate<std::size_t, std::size_t> F>
std::vector<bool> checkSurroundings(Image const& image, F&& f, std::size_t x0, std::size_t y0) {
  std::vector<std::array<std::size_t,2>> stack;
  stack.push_back({x0,y0});

  if (image.empty()) return {};

  std::size_t const w = image.size();
  std::vector<bool> seen(w*image[0].size());

  while (!stack.empty()) {
    auto const expand = [&](std::size_t const x, std::size_t const y) {
      if (x >= image.size()) return; // enough because of unsigned underflow
      if (y >= image[x].size()) return; // same
      if (seen[x+w*y]) return;
      if (!f(x,y)) return;
      stack.push_back({x,y});
      seen[x+w*y] = true;
    };
    auto const [x,y] = stack.back();
    stack.pop_back();
    expand(x+1,y);
    expand(x-1,y);
    expand(x,y+1);
    expand(x,y-1);
  }
  return seen;
}

std::vector<bool> MWT(const Image& image,
                                   std::size_t x, std::size_t y,
                                   std::int32_t t) {
  return checkSurroundings(image, [&](auto x0, auto y0){
    return std::abs(image[x][y] - image[x0][y0]) <= t;
  }, x, y);
}
```

I also took the liberty to change the type of your "seen" lookup to reduce the amount of allocations.

([compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zo3T7nd5M))

Comment: Would that make sense to use [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) for `stack` instead? Semantically, if believe it would, but I did not test if this would impact performance positively or not (assuming using default underlying `std::dequeue`).

Comment: @Erel std::stack is a wrapper around an std::deque, which, while being really performant, is still worse than an std::vector. You can also change the underlying container to a vector, yes, but I don't see much point in taking the detour. My code above neglects to pre-allocate memory. It would probably be sped up a lot if you `stack.reserve(width*height);`.